# A mysterious thing I am

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

So you say now I am not what you used to say I was? You've kicked me out of the group you used to say I was a member of? Well, without me the other members of the group are eaten, ungrammatically. But say what you wish; it makes no difference to me. I was here long before you ever existed, and I'll probably be here long after you're gone. To date I have been mostly unreachable for you, though lately you have been doing some probing into my business. Really, it's been less than half a year that you've even known of my existence, though you would say it's been 90.

I don't mean to sound bitter about any of this; I'm really very ambivalent. If I sound cold, well, that's because I am. *Very.*

We are distant and different, you know. What is bright and blinding for you is only a glimmer for me. And yet in a way, I am in your element. You named me after one thing and then named another thing after me; the second thing being the first in reverse.

Knowing me well, as I have said, would be difficult for you. And maybe you don't want to dive deep into learning about me right now. But you can at least learn my name by solving this riddle; taking a partial plunge, to which you must add.

I am __________

Comment: I am __________ --> frustrated ---- ten underscores, ten letters.

Comment: @riskymysteries I can change the number if it would be helpful

Comment: No, I'm good :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you

> Pluto

So you say now I am not what you used to say I was? You've kicked me out of the group you used to say I was a member of?

> Pluto is not longer a planet, but rather a dwarf planet.

Well, without me the other members of the group are eaten, ungrammatically. But say what you wish; it makes no difference to me.

> Instead of 9 planets in our solar system, there are now 8(ate)!

I was here long before you ever existed, and I'll probably be here long after you're gone. To date I have been mostly unreachable for you, though lately you have been doing some probing into my business. Really, it's been less than half a year that you've even known of my existence, though you would say it's been 90.

> Pluto is very old just like the rest of the universe. The New horizons probe recently completed a fly by Pluto(ending in 2019). This was the first time we have seen Pluto close up. Also, Pluto was discovered it 1930, so 90 years ago. Ninety Earth years is equivalent to two-fifths of a Pluto year(Thank you Gary Gary Botnovcan!)

I don't mean to sound bitter about any of this; I'm really very ambivalent. If I sound cold, well, that's because I am. Very.
We are distant and different, you know. What is bright and blinding for you is only a glimmer for me.

> Pluto is quiet far away from the sun meaning that it is below freezing and not very visible. Also, Earthlings cannot stare at the sun due to its intensity, however that is no problem for Pluto.

And yet in a way, I am in your element. You named me after one thing and then named another thing after me; the second thing being the first in reverse.

> Pluto is a name from classical mythology. Pluto was a god of the underworld, the planet was named after the mythology and then later Disney named a dog after the planet. Dog is god in reverse.  The letter initials of PL are in reference to [Percival Lowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percival_Lowell). Also Plutonium is element number 94 on the periodic table.

Knowing me well, as I have said, would be difficult for you. And maybe you don't want to dive deep into learning about me right now. But you can at least learn my name by solving this riddle; taking a partial plunge, to which you must add.

> Pluto is not yet on the earth travel-radar. We have private space launches and Mars to worry about. Kate Gregory in the comments mentioned that if you take a partial "plu" from "plunge" and add "to", you get Pluto!

Comment: I think you've got it, but I'm not positive. Did you say what you meant to in your initial answer?

Comment: Oh no, that was a mistake! I edited it now :) @Ilak

Comment: Great! And it looks like you're beginning to find the other clues, so even better!

Comment: @Ilak, I think I got most of it now!

Comment: You're getting there! But there are still a few things you're missing, and your explanations of the last and second-to-last paragraphs aren't what I was thinking of

Comment: cnegvny cyhatr vf cyh naq gura "gb juvpu lbh zhfg nqq" znxrf cyh-gb

Comment: nyfb, cyhgbavhz vf na ryrzrag, though I don't get the reverse part

Comment: Got it! Cyhgb jnf n tbq bs gur haqrejbeyq, gur cynarg jnf anzrq nsgre gur qbt naq gura yngre Qvfarl anzrq n qbt nsgre gur cynarg. Qbt vf Tbq va erirefr.

Comment: You're getting there! Both the things you added are correct (though I think you meant gur cynarg jnf anzrq nsgre gur tbq, abe qbt.) But there's another explanation for the part about avargl lrnef if. yrff guna n unys lrne. And there's one wordplay you're missing besides the one you know about. Also, the Crepviny Ybjryy thing was not intentional on my part but it's a good addition!

Comment: Eaten ungrammatically?  Zl irel raretrgvp zbgure whfg freirq hf avar

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan That's not what I had in mind, but I like it!

Comment: Actually, I wasn't thinking about the mnemonic at all with "eaten, ungrammatically", so you're on the wrong track

Comment: Bx, svar, Zbgure freirq hf naq jr'er abg rngra, jr'er ngr cynargf abj.  Onu. Ol gur jnl, vg'f orra avargl lrnef sbe hf, ohg ubj znal sbe Cyhgb vgfrys?  Naq, jbhyq vg rira abgvpr vgf ntr, fvapr vg unf "bayl n tyvzzre sbe zr" zbivat guebhtu vgf fxl gb znex vg?

Comment: @Ilak, edited that part now! Thanks Gary Botnovcan

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan You're right about everything! There is just one pun left to find

Comment: You're welcome.  Also note:  Lbh zvffrq gung avargl lrnef sbe hf vf nobhg gjb-svsguf bs n lrne sbe gur qvfgnag qjnes.  Yrff guna n unys na beovg, lbh frr.

Comment: QuantumTwinkie, Gary Botnovcan was on to something with the glimmar as well

Comment: Also, I still think you're saying "qbt" in one place where you mean "tbq"

Comment: Got it! @Ilak :)

Comment: Cyhgb'f rppragevp, ohg gung qbrfa'g znxr vg nzovinyrag.  Puneba, ubjrire, graqf gb guebj uvf jrvtug nebhaq dhvgr n ovg.  V'z abg fher ubj V srry nobhg gung.

Comment: I will accept this answer eventually whether you find one remaining pun or not, but I'm going to give you a little time to look for it first

Comment: @Ilak  Thanks, I will keep looking. Great riddle with so many little clues in each line!

Comment: Huh, @Ilak.  Now I can't tell how I feel about getting that last pun, and I'd bet that my neighbors are ambivalent, too.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan No pressure to keep looking if you don't feel like it

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, since after all that doesn't keep anyone from looking. QuantumTwinkie, I'm glad you liked the riddle!

Comment: But, @Ilak, that sounds like you didn't notice or didn't understand my response about "nzovinyrapr", which looks like the only pun not yet in the answer proper.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I did see that, but I probably didn't understand. (I'm not very fluent in rot 13 yet so maybe I missed something.) But I don't think you were referring to the pun I'm thinking of. I would like to know what I'm missing, though.

Comment: Puneba, ubjrire, graqf gb guebj uvf jrvtug nebhaq dhvgr n ovg. Fb zhpu fb gung vg chyyf Cyhgb va rirel qverpgvba (nzov-inyrag) nebhaq gurve pbzzba onelpragre.  And sites like https://cryptii.com/pipes/rot13-decoder make fluency irrelevant ; )

Comment: Ah, I see! That was a purely unintentional pun. And thanks for the link; it's very helpful!

Comment: This answer have better explanation than mine.

Comment: There's "fnl jung lbh jvfu", there's "gb fbhaq ovgre", and there's "ernyl irel nzovinyrag".  I got "nzovinyrag" wrong.  I've got nothing for the other two.  Everything else seems answered.  That "one remaining pun" is more mysterious than the whole riddle's answer.  I can't find a place for it to fit.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Do you want a hint?

Comment: I'd be delighted, @Ilak.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Major hint or minor hint?

Comment: Aw, c'mon.  No way to answer that until it's too late.  Use your judgement.

Comment: Okay. Ernq gur guveq cnentencu bs DhnaghzGjvaxvr'f rkcynangvba ntnva. Gur pehgvny jbeqf vf nyernql va gur nafjre, ohg gur cha vf abg cbvagrq bhg

Comment: Bu.  Uzz.  Gung? Sebz zl crefcrpgvir, gung qvqa'g rira ybbx yvxr vg'f bhg bs obhaqf, yrg nybar bire gur ubevmba.  Vg whfg ybbxf yvxr n fbyhgvba.  Ohg, znlor V pna frr guvatf lbhe jnl.  Vs V pna zbir zl crefcrpgvir zhpu zhpu *zhpu* pybfre, gur cha zvtug or whfg orlbaq gur arj ubevmbaf.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Indeed it is!

Answer (score 2):

Just an attempt; may not match each statement of your puzzle.

Are you

> The [Pluto Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto)?

A mysterious thing I am

> We know the planet and few facts about it. But, there are many mysteries about it yet to be reveled.

So you say now I am not what you used to say I was? You've kicked me out of the group you used to say I was a member of?

> It was used to be called "Planet". Now, it is shifted to "Dwarf Planet" category.

Well, without me the other members of the group are eaten, ungrammatically.

> While formation of solar system, many other small objects were merged in bigger objects. This one survived. That said, other small objects were eaten up by large objects.

But say what you wish; it makes no difference to me.

> It is material, non-living thing. It makes no difference to it what we call it or in what category we put it.

I was here long before you ever existed, and I'll probably be here long after you're gone.

> Of-course; isn't it? Considering "you" as I individual or a human, the statement is true.

To date I have been mostly unreachable for you,

> "mostly unreachable", yes. We have not yet landed on it.

though lately you have been doing some probing into my business.

> Human have sent many un-manned space ships to investigate solar system and other parts of universe. I guess "probing" is pointing to it.

Really, it's been less than half a year that you've even known of my existence, though you would say it's been 90.

> Don't know. Not sure if this is about "year of Pluto". I will investigate further.

I don't mean to sound bitter about any of this; I'm really very ambivalent.

> Humans have contradictory ideas about it; some say Planet and some say Dwarf Planet.

If I sound cold, well, that's because I am. Very.

> It *is* cold, very cold planet (or Dwarf Planet).

We are distant and different, you know.

> Not sure but if we compare Pluto with Earth, yes; they are distant and different.

What is bright and blinding for you is only a glimmer for me.

> The Sun that looks very bright and is blinding from Earth is glimmer on Pluto.

And yet in a way, I am in your element.

> Don't know. May be chemical elements forming Pluto and Earth are same?

You named me after one thing and then named another thing after me; the second thing being the first in reverse.

> Partial answer. Planet was named Pluto after "[Roman god of the underworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_(mythology))". Don't know what other thing that was named after Pluto.

Knowing me well, as I have said, would be difficult for you.

> Not sure but to know about this planet more, human need to spend too much money. Distance is too long; it is hard to reach and come back from there; we do not have that technology yet. That is why, it is difficult.

And maybe you don't want to dive deep into learning about me right now.

> Not sure but "dive deep" into the Pluto will kill (obviously) the human.

Comment: This answer has already been posted, with more detail. Please check other answers before posting your own.

Answer (score 1):

I am

> you too

thus it shall be

> we

Comment: I like the speed.